# Rails activerecord query function in order by function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I do something like this

```
self.order("extract(year, day), extract(month, day)")
```

I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESC"
LINE 19: ...>= '08-01-2012') GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY extract(year DESC, day)...
```

is there a way to format this query properly with activerecord?

Comment: You need to `select` from an ActiveRecord subclass for `order` to make sense. What's the context?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing what the error suggests you to do:

```
extract(year DESC, day)
```